# Get last inserted id using mysql2 gem

Tags: mysql, ruby

I have code like this:

```
   require 'mysql2' 
   @db.query("insert into clients (Name) values ('#{client}')")
```

Can I return last inserted id with 1 query?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `last_id` method of the client instance:

```
client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root", :password => "", :database => "db")
insert = client.query "INSERT INTO test (name, date) VALUES ('name', '2011-11-28 09:13:56')"
id = client.last_id
```

http://rubydoc.info/gems/mysql2/0.2.6/Mysql2/Client:last_id

**Edit**: it doesn't answer your original question but still looks better than call for LAST_INSERT_ID

Answer (score 3):

I don't anything about gem but you can try to run

```
@db.query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();")
```

after your first query.

Comment: thnx, I know about it. 
In postgres I can do it in 1 query with keyword RETURNING id, and I wanna use at mysql something like this